# Combine text from multiple rows into one cell based on unique text match?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table like so:

[image: Data Set]

Based on this set, I need "summary records" for each unique SKU prefix, e.g. PW0007 and PW0008 in this example). Here's an example:

[image: Desired Result]
Just in case this is difficult to read, here's an example of one of the variation outputs (G1) above:

sku=PW0007BG-3x6-M,color=Beige,size=3x6,finish=Matte,look=Wood,application=Wall or Floor|sku=PW0007BK-3x6-M,color=Black,size=3x6,finish=Matte,look=Wood,application=Wall or Floor|sku=PW0007RD-4x8-P,color=Red,size=4x8,finish=Polished,look=Wood,application=Wall or Floor

One more point is that I have the SKU field broken out into its various parts on a separate sheet, such that I can easily do a UNIQUE() and get the Prefix PW0007 and PW0008 if that's the best approach. It's getting the variations for each unique SKU prefix and separating them that I can't begin to imagine. Maybe some kind of SUMPRODUCT?

I'd like to dream this is possible via a formula, but I'm more inclined to think I'll need some kind of script which is a whole 'nother ball of wax for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a script for this; a combination of spreadsheet formulas suffices. For the same of simplicity I assume that your data is in columns A-F and the output will be in G-H of the same sheet.

First, generate a list of unique prefixes. Assuming they are the first 6 characters of SKU, the formula (placed in G2) would be

```
=sort(unique(filter(left(A2:A, 6), len(A2:A))))
```

(sort is optional, but makes sense to do in this context). The filter removes empty lines from consideration.

Then in the next column, use this longish formula in cell H2, presented here with line breaks.

```
=join("|", arrayformula("sku=" & filter(A2:A, left(A2:A, 6) = G2)  
    & ",color=" & filter(B2:B, left(A2:A, 6) = G2)
    & ",size=" & filter(C2:C, left(A2:A, 6) = G2)
    & ",finish=" & filter(D2:D, left(A2:A, 6) = G2)
    & ",look=" & filter(E2:E, left(A2:A,6) = G2)
    & ",application=" & filter(E2:E, left(A2:A,6) = G2)
))
```

Despite the length, it's pretty straightforward: filter each column by the SKU prefix, prepend its description, and concatenate the results. The final step is to join all such results.

The formula from H2 needs to be dragged down the H column.

Comment: thanks so much for a clear and concise answer which helpfully explained the concepts involved in the solution as well as provided the solution to try.  I'll give this a go and accept the answer once tested and confirmed.

Comment: I made some adaptations for this as my "G2" is actually on another sheet. It works swimmingly, thanks.  If I have additional questions related to this, should I continue to ask them here, or through another question?

Comment: does this work if the two sets of data are on different sheets?  E.g, based on a shared SKU prefix, the values for color, size, finish, et. al, can be filtered on another sheet?

Comment: Yes, the two ranges in the `filter` formula can be on different sheets. All that matters is having the same number of rows.

Comment: Thanks!  This answers the question I asked; however, I realize now that I didn't ask the question the right way, which sucks, and is my own fault.  If I try to ask it again the right way, would you mind taking a look, as I think you could easily adapt this, and I've been trying to for the last 2 hours.

Comment: Sure, ask another question.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try here. I decided that rather than try to explain, I'd build out a better example which shows an idea of the dispersement of fields between the different sheets, and the two approaches for the data entry and result sheets, respectively.  Just a note that there are other sheets the values come from, I kept it simpler for clarity. Whenever there are collections of "simple" rows, know that the number of these rows is always variable. [Here's the file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FC3A5YWY_nnpelG-suthuxciBx0-97bHi5elB0j_5_g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Pardon me for belaboring the point, but in the interest of clarity and thoroughness, I thought I'd mention that the formulas for combining and moving text are just there for convenience in the example.  They're different in the real thing.  I don't **think** it matters how the data gets into the sheet?  (As an example, the color and size abbreviations are compared to named ranges and then brought in on the fly, etc.)  Will the method in which the data comes into the result sheet affect the result?